# I am getting a message in console saying "Missing MeshRenderables for ground..." in my React Native App?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am getting follow message in console app, I was looking in the internet but nothing to solve this message. I am currently working wiht React-Native-Maps package.

[VectorKit] Missing MeshRenderables for ground mesh layer for (1/1) of ground tiles. Tile debug info: (Key:
82.194.9.255 t:34 kt:0, Has mesh errors: 0, MeshInstance count: 1, PendingMaterial count: 1, Invisible MeshInstances
count: 0)

This is how my code looks:

```
    <MapView
                            style={{
                              width: width / 1.2,
                              height: 150,
                              borderRadius: 20,
                            }}
                            initialRegion={{
                              latitude: Number(item.latitude),
                              longitude: Number(item.longitude),
                              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                            }}
                            minZoomLevel={13}
                            zoomEnabled={true}
                          >
                            <Marker
                              coordinate={{
                                latitude: Number(item.latitude),
                                longitude: Number(item.longitude),
                              }}
                            />
                          </MapView>
```